# How to monitor real time system performance for ARM running linux on it?

Tags: linux, performance, arm, system

How can i monitor system performance of ARM CPU cores real time running linux OS on it? Is there any graphical tool available? On my X86 desktop running ubuntu there is system monitor. Is there something similar for ARM?

Comment: i don't know how things work under the hood for system monitoring for linux OS for ARM.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

System performance can be monitored by using sar utility in Linux

"man sar" command will show you all the system performance metrics which can be monitored

"sar -A" will give you all the metrics

collect the sar output and sadf utility will provide all metrics in csv format and plotters will plot nice graphs from it which can be used for analysis.
there are other tools also which will analyze sar output also and provide you the statistics.

for graphical UI, Linux has its own performance monitor UI which will show you system performance details (internally which also uses sar only)